# Datatable.Load does not work with SqlCeReader

Tags: c#, datatable, connection, sql-server-ce, datareader

I have this method:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(IDbConnection connection, string cmdText)
{
    IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = cmdText;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    return dt;
}
```

When i execute the query `select * from information_schema.Tables` against a connection of type SQLConnection it all works.
However, when I try to run it against a connection of type `SqlCEConnection` the line `dt.Load(reader)` raises an exception:

```
System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

Comment: You can always look into the `DataTable` to see what caused a `ConstraintException`. Set a breakpoint right at the line `dt.Load(reader);`. User a [Quick-Watch Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx) to execute this line. Then you can get all rows with errors with `dt.GetErrors()`. Then you can look into each returned DataRow's [`RowError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowerror.aspx) property to see the actual reason.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the GetErrors() method. I get this: RowError: "Column 'DATE_MODIFIED' does not allow DBNull.Value."
SqlCE seems to return some more columns than SQL Server 2005 but leaves them on NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly a weird issue but here's an alternative:

Read the data into a DataSet and set the EnforceConstraints to false. You could then return  `DataSet.Tables[0]`

Comment: Thanks. I now use the dataset in combination with EnforceConstraints=false which works for me.